# Substituting number into file name in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to download multiple files such as:

```
www.example.com/v1/file.txt
www.example.com/v2/file.txt
www.example.com/v3/file.txt
...
```

The following command doesn't work, as it actually looks for a file  "r{1..99}/file.txt":

```
for i in {10..99}
do
 wget "www.example.com/v"$i"/file.txt" -O "file_"$i".txt"
done
```

It also makes no difference if I put additional quotes " " around $i. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example code works here (well, except of course for the 404 errors from example.com). Are you sure you're running it in bash? If so, which version of bash? (Can we get the output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`?)

Comment: for me is looking for `http://www.example.com/v{10..99}/file.txt`. That is from v10 to v99...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your variable name inside curly braces like this:

```
for i in {10..99} ; do echo wget "www.example.com/v${i}/file.txt" ; done
```

Misread question. seq or set -B is the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with **seq** command:

```
for i in $(seq 10 99)
do
 wget "www.example.com/v"$i"/file.txt" -O "file_"$i".txt"
done
```

This works for me using **3.2.51(1)-release** *(last stable version is 4.2)*:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Or just maybe you are using another shell:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are using an older version of bash or `sh` that does not support brace expansion. Try this instead:

```
for i in $(seq 10 99); 
do
 wget www.example.com/v"$i"/file.txt -O file_"$i".txt
done
```

Another possibility is that you have disabled brace expansion, you can turn it on with `set -B` and off with `set +B`:

```
$ set +B
$ echo {1..10}
{1..10}
$ set -B
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```